# Trying to avoid circular dependency in c# Windows Application

Tags: c#

I am trying to add a function into an existing product during my internship. I am working with a multi project solution. For the purpose of this question, I will just limit it to two projects (1 & 2). Project 1 is referencing Project 2.

Upon clicking a button in Project 1 I want to change the value of a variable that is inside of Project 2. This is needed in order to have a certain portion of code activate only when the button is clicked. However, due to Project 2 not being able to reference Project 1 (circular dependency), it cannot see the variable change that was just made in Project 1.

I am aware of the usefulness of event handlers and event subscription but Project 2 cannot see any event handlers from Project 1 because again, it is not referenced. I am also aware that this is not the way solutions should be designed but I didn't create the product I am simply trying to add a feature.

My ultimate questions is: How can I have Project 2 perform differently based on a change or event that occurs in Project 1.

Comment: We will need more information than that. What type of projects are they? Are both of them runnable projects, or are they libraries? WHy can you separate the conflicting logic into a separate project with common code both projects will have access to.

Comment: If `Project1` has a reference to `Project2`, why can it not just do `project2.Property = someValue;`?

Comment: Here is something that may help. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/306483/how-to-solve-circular-dependency